# zend http client programming issue

Tags: zend-framework

I have a url where we pass two parameters namely ip address and mac address. Now, I want to use Zend_Http_Client to post those parameters to the url.
However, the ip address and mac address that I will be passing to the url are in an array which is stored in a variable. So, how should I go about using
setParameterPost in this case.

For example,

```
public function ex($values)
{
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://someurl.com');
    $client->setParameterPost();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [ZF documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.http.client.html#zend.http.client.parameters), you should be able to just pass the key->value array to the method `setParameterPost()`. Like this:

```
$client->setParameterPost(array(
    'ip'  => '127.0.0.1',
    'mac'   => 'someDataI'
));
```

**EDIT:**

If I understand your comment correctly, what you want to do is:

```
public function ex($values)
{
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://someurl.com');
    $client->setParameterPost($ext);
}
```

Here I assume, that the variable `$ext` is an array containing elements with keys *ip* and *mac*, or any other name, that you want for your parameter names. Zend does not care about what you name your post parameters.

Comment: Actually, $values is the variable containing the array. so, I wanted to know if $client->setParameterPost($values) would work.

Comment: If the array is in the form `key=>value` then yes. Though the best way to do this is to try it out ;)